# Anycast on Docker/Containers

Tags: docker, networking, podman, anycast

I am trying to add multiple containers to the same ip address in order to have an anycast group. This doesn't work as expected because ip addresses cannot be assigned multiple times. However, this leaves me wondering how I can get docker or other container tools like podman to create an anycast network.

Sure there are other ways to archive similar behaviours, however, I am trying to "play around" with anycast and containers to simulate a network and you could consider this as a personal research trying to understand networks and the possibilities of anycast.

I searched for quite some time but could not find anything reliable information to archive this behaviour. I found [this github project](https://github.com/kd7lxl/docker-anycast-service-discovery) which seems to create interfaces and tries to "bypass" the docker networking but this doesn't seem to work.

I found some information in research papers that virtual networks are unable to "speek" anycast but there has to be a way somehow. There is hardly anything impossible.

A device cannot "speak" anycast, it is the result of routing and cost updates - I am aware of that.
Is there a way on how I can archive anycast with docker?

Comment: Surely since anycast is something you need to support at the network-routing layer, that's where you need to start? It's not about the containers as such, it's about the virtual network stack they connect to. You need to find a virtual network stack / write your own that can handle that.

Comment: You are right. However, it is hard for me to believe that such things aren't built-in... 